# How to get highest number while in foreach loop

Tags: php

I have a function that returns mp3 list with its qualities. I want to return HD value true if I reach the last element in the array but i have a problem in foreach loop. It always returns true.

Code

```
   function funcName() {
    foreach($dirs as $d) {
        if (filesize($d) > 200) {
            $qualities = substr(strrchr(basename($d), "-"), 1);
            $qualities = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $qualities);
            // This is where I check whether it is the last element or not.
            $numItems = count($dirs);
            $i = 0;
            foreach($dirs as $key => $value) {
                if (++$i === $numItems) {
                    $zaa = true;
                } else {
                    $zaa = false;
                }
            }
            $files[] = ["files" => basename($d), "qualities" => $qualities, "hd" => $zaa];
        }
    }
    return ($files);
}
```

I just want to return `$zaa = true` if I reach to the last element. In my code, **it returns true all the time**.

Could you please show me in whic part am I failing?

Comment: Place your count($dirs) above your foreach loop, every iteration you're recalculating the the size of the array/collection. This is for performance not a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this should work:

```
function funcName() {

$numItems = count($dirs);
$i = 0;
foreach($dirs as $d) {
$i++;
    if (filesize($d) > 200) {
        $qualities = substr(strrchr(basename($d), "-"), 1);
        $qualities = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $qualities);         
        if ($i == $numItems) {
            $zaa = true;
        } else {
            $zaa = false;
        }            
        $files[] = ["files" => basename($d), "qualities" => $qualities, "hd" => $zaa];
    }
}
return ($files);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this worked thank you very much I came up with another solution but I will mark your question as correct thanks!:)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to loop `$dirs` again, just do it like this:

```
function funcName() {
    $i = 1;
    $numItems = count($dirs);
    foreach($dirs as $d) {
        $i++;
        $zaa = $i === $numItems;
        if (filesize($d) > 200) {
            $qualities = substr(strrchr(basename($d), "-"), 1);
            $qualities = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $qualities);
            // This is where I check whether it is the last element or not.
            $numItems = count($dirs);

            $files[] = ["files" => basename($d), "qualities" => $qualities, "hd" => $zaa];
        }
    }
    return ($files);
}
```

Comment: That didn't work, still returns true for all of the results :(

Comment: @LunaticFnatic I edited my answer. You don't need to loop through `$dirs` twice, actually it wouldn't work anyway.

Comment: Thank you, I upvoted your answe too, it works as intended but I came up with another solution :)

Comment: @LunaticFnatic no problems, as soon as you get it to work as you expect, it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can change your condition by below condition. if your key started with 0 then you need to (sizeof($dirs) - 1) to get the total array element.

```
 if(sizeof($dirs) == $key)
```

Comment: That still returns true for all of the results

Answer (score 0):

Use for loop instead , if you are using count() and all those statements it's just adding useless lines to your code, for(){} will be shorter and less complex

Comment: btw that TRUE comes from secound loop inside 1st loop, that makes no sense, just put those lines outside or you are reaching last item in that loop every time and receiving true

Comment: Is there any easier solution to check last element without the second foreach or count()? and if possible could you please give an example with forloop version? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I posted new answer, still using foreach, just because I was too lazy, and I didn't say you need to get rid of count(), you were just using it wrong

Answer (score 0):

Both of the answers are correct below, but I came up with this solution seems faster;

```
 if ($d === end($dirs)) {
    $zaa = true;
 } else {
    $zaa = false;
 }
```